# Modal (boot-strap) in rails 4 not working now since upgrading from rails 3 to rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, bootstrap-modal

I recently started working to bring some of my older Rails 3 apps up to Rails 4. I have a modal that I use for users to input data. The thing is that since upgrading my modal will not work. The screen will dim like its going to show up but nothing does. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Gemfile.Lock:

```
bootstrap-sass (3.3.5.1)
sass (3.4.16)
sass-rails (5.0.3)
  railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
  sass (~> 3.1)
  sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
  sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
  tilt (~> 1.1)
```

Application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.ui.all
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require best_in_place
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require jquery.scrollTo
//= require floatlabel
//= require gritter
```

Style sheet:

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'jquery.ui.all';
@import "font-awesome";
@import "gritter";
```

My view:

```
%td.b.trace-table
  .row-fluid
    .span12
      %a{:href => "#time-entry", :role => "button", :class => "btn btn-primary", 'data-toggle' => "modal", 'data-target' => "#time-entry",'data-type' => "html"}Time Entry
      #time-entry.modal.hide
        =render "modal", :entry => e
```

Here is my modal:

```
.modal-header
  %button{:type => "button", :id => "close_modal", :class => "close", :'data-dismiss' => "modal"}×
.modal-body
  = simple_form_for @labor, :html => {:class => 'form-inline'} do |f|
    = f.input :good_qty,           :as => "hidden", :label => false, :input_html => {:value => '0'}
    = f.input :bad_qty,            :as => "hidden", :label => false, :input_html => {:value => '0'}
    %table.table.table-striped
      %tbody
        %tr
          %td.lt User ID:
          %td.lt= f.input :user_id, :label => false, :readonly => true, :input_html => {:value => current.user.id}
          %td.lt Date:
          %td.lt= f.input :create_date, :as => :string, :label => false, :readonly => true, :input_html => {:value => current.date}
        %tr
          %td.lt Hours Worked:
          %td.lt= f.input :hours_worked, :label => false
        %tr
          %td.lt PIN:
          %td.lt= f.input :pin, :label => false, :input_html => { :password => 'password' }
    = f.button :submit, "Submit", :class => "btn btn-primary"
.modal-footer
```

Before I click time entry

[image]

After I click time entry

[image]

Comment: Are there any errors appearing in your browsers console when you try to open the modal?

Comment: no errors in my firefox console. @Adrian Mann what's weird is it worked with rails 3 so my guess I'm thinking is it has to be something to do with bootstrap gem -v not 100% sure on that.

Comment: i managed to recreate your problem. I'll give you a solution as soon as I fix it

Comment: Okay thank you so much! @Hristo Georgiev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove your `.hide` class. The modal is hidden without it and it stays hidden when you open it.

```
  #time-entry.modal
    =render "modal", :entry => e
```

I also had to rename some of the requires in order to make my application work (I used the same gems as you did)

```
@import 'jquery-ui';
```

in application.css.scss and

```
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
```

in application.js

p.s I used  jquery-ui-rails (5.0.5).

[image: Your modal with the view]

Comment: The hide class was commented out so I don't think that it was a factor?

Comment: That's not a comment. It stands for an id of a <div> element in HAML

Comment: I have it hidden but when the user presses the button it appears.

Comment: Isn't that what a modal is supposed to do?

Comment: That's what I want it to do basically the user clicks on the button and it pops up, but if they dont that modal will stay hidden. It works perfectly on rails 3, I just want to have the same outcome on rails 4 so, thats where Im stuck at the page dims like usually but my model input view will not show up. so I know my toggle is working @HristoGeorgiev

Comment: @Snowman, I added a screenshot. This is what you want to see pop up once the 'Time Entry' button is pressed, correct?

Comment: correct let me take a quick snap shot to show you what's happening. @HristoGeorgiev

Comment: We can continue the discussion in a chatroom:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87795/boostrap-modals

Comment: I added my screen shots of what is happening @HristoGeorgiev

Comment: See that <div id="time-entry" class="modal hide> tag? Make it <div id="time-entry" class="modal"> . Remove the .hide class and tell me what happens.

Comment: I had written this in the original answer, but you disregarded it. Read more carefully next time, it'll save you a lot of nerves and effort. Cheers!